# Finding the best pair of elements that don't exceed a certain weight?

Tags: algorithm, optimization

I have a collection of objects, each of which has a weight and a value.  I want to pick the pair of objects with the highest total value subject to the restriction that their combined weight does not exceed some threshold.  Additionally, I am given two arrays, one containing the objects sorted by weight and one containing the objects sorted by value.

I know how to do it in O(n<sup>2</sup>) but how can I do it in O(n)?

Comment: num is a property of obj? Are there any realtion between num and val within single object?

Comment: I am thinking iterating over the array, first I will put the first two objects that have obj1.num+obj2.num < limit, and then let's sat that obj1 has lower val, I will look for an obj with higher val and that obj.num+obj2.num < limit.
is it good for all cases?

Comment: num and val are two int properties of obj, the list is of the same type of obj,obj1,obj2...

Comment: do you know for sure that this can be done in o(n^2) and even in O(n) or it's just a supposition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an **O(n)** time, O(1) space solution.

Let's call an object x *better than* an object y if and only if (x is no heavier than y) and (x is no less valuable) and (x is lighter or more valuable). Call an object x *first-choice* if no object is better than x. There exists an optimal solution consisting either of two first-choice objects, or a first-choice object x and an object y such that only x is better than y.

The main tool is to be able to iterate the first-choice objects from lightest to heaviest (= least valuable to most valuable) and from most valuable to least valuable (= heaviest to lightest). The iterator state is an index into the objects by weight (resp. value) and a max value (resp. min weight) so far.

Each of the following steps is O(n).

1. During a scan, whenever we encounter an object that is not first-choice, we know an object that's better than it. Scan once and consider these pairs of objects.
2. For each first-choice object from lightest to heaviest, determine the heaviest first-choice object that it can be paired with, and consider the pair. (All lighter objects are less valuable.) Since the latter object becomes lighter over time, each iteration of the loop is amortized O(1). (See also searching in a matrix whose rows and columns are sorted.)

---

Code for the unbelievers. Not heavily tested.

```
from collections import namedtuple
from operator import attrgetter

Item = namedtuple('Item', ('weight', 'value'))

sentinel = Item(float('inf'), float('-inf'))

def firstchoicefrombyweight(byweight):
    bestsofar = sentinel
    for x in byweight:
        if x.value > bestsofar.value:
            bestsofar = x
        yield (x, bestsofar)

def firstchoicefrombyvalue(byvalue):
    bestsofar = sentinel
    for x in byvalue:
        if x.weight < bestsofar.weight:
            bestsofar = x
            yield x

def optimize(items, maxweight):
    byweight = sorted(items, key=attrgetter('weight'))
    byvalue = sorted(items, key=attrgetter('value'), reverse=True)
    maxvalue = float('-inf')
    try:
        i = firstchoicefrombyvalue(byvalue)
        y = i.next()
        for x, z in firstchoicefrombyweight(byweight):
            if z is not x and x.weight + z.weight <= maxweight:
                maxvalue = max(maxvalue, x.value + z.value)
            while x.weight + y.weight > maxweight:
                y = i.next()
            if y is x:
                break
            maxvalue = max(maxvalue, x.value + y.value)
    except StopIteration:
      pass
    return maxvalue

items = [Item(1, 1), Item(2, 2), Item(3, 5), Item(3, 7), Item(5, 8)]
for maxweight in xrange(3, 10):
    print maxweight, optimize(items, maxweight)
```

Comment: How do you do these two steps in O(n) time?

Comment: @templatetypedef, As a slightly simplified problem, consider being allowed to pick two of the same item.  Now you only need to pick items that are first choice (non-dominated).  For every item, every other item has either higher value or lower weight.  Now as you walk through the optimal frontier increasing weight order, the opt pair for a given item must have less weight but more value.  So at every step either you move the weight index up, or the value index down.  Getting rid of no dup restriction is akin to finding the 2nd max in an array, annoying, but asymptotically the same.

Answer (score 3):

This is a combinatorial optimization problem, and the fact the values are sorted means you can easily try a [branch and bound](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_and_bound) approach.

Comment: But does this give any guarantees at all to be O(n) (or even O(n^2), for that matter?)

Comment: Yes.  Proving sub quadratic time isn't hard and is worth trying.

Answer (score 3):

I think that I have a solution that works in O(n log n) time and O(n) extra space.  This isn't quite the O(n) solution you wanted, but it's still better than the naive quadratic solution.

The intuition behind the algorithm is that we want to be able to efficiently determine, for any amount of weight, the maximum value we can get with a single item that uses at most that much weight.  If we can do this, we have a simple algorithm for solving the problem: iterate across the array of elements sorted by value.  For each element, see how much additional value we could get by pairing a single element with it (using the values we precomputed), then find which of these pairs is maximum.  If we can do the preprocessing in O(n log n) time and can answer each of the above queries in O(log n) time, then the total time for the second step will be O(n log n) and we have our answer.

An important observation we need to do the preprocessing step is as follows.  Our goal is to build up a structure that can answer the question "which element with weight less than x has maximum value?" Let's think about how we might do this by adding one element at a time.  If we have an element (value, weight) and the structure is empty, then we want to say that the maximum value we can get using weight at most "weight" is "value".  This means that everything in the range [0, max_weight - weight) should be set to value.  Otherwise, suppose that the structure isn't empty when we try adding in (value, weight).  In that case, we want to say that any portion of the range [0, weight) whose value is less than value should be replaced by value.

The problem here is that when we do these insertions, there might be, on iteration k, O(k) different subranges that need to be updated, leading to an O(n<sup>2</sup>) algorithm.  However, we can use a very clever trick to avoid this.  Suppose that we insert all of the elements into this data structure in descending order of value.  In that case, when we add in (value, weight), because we add the elements in descending order of value, each existing value in the data structure must be higher than our value.  This means that if the range [0, weight) intersects any range at all, those ranges will automatically be higher than value and so we don't need to update them.  If we combine this with the fact that each range we add always spans from zero to some value, the only portion of the new range that could ever be added to the data structure is the range [weight, x), where x is the highest weight stored in the data structure so far.

To summarize, assuming that we visit the (value, weight) pairs in descending order of value, we can update our data structure as follows:

1. If the structure is empty, record that the range [0, value) has value "value."
2. Otherwise, if the highest weight recorded in the structure is greater than weight, skip this element.
3. Otherwise, if the highest weight recorded so far is x, record that the range [weight, x) has value "value."

Notice that this means that we are always splitting ranges at the front of the list of ranges we have encountered so far.  Because of this, we can think about storing the list of ranges as a simple array, where each array element tracks the upper endpoint of some range and the value assigned to that range.  For example, we might track the ranges [0, 3), [3, 9), and [9, 12) as the array

```
3, 9, 12
```

If we then needed to split the range [0, 3) into [0, 1) and [1, 3), we could do so by prepending 1 to he list:

```
1, 3, 9, 12
```

If we represent this array in reverse (actually storing the ranges from high to low instead of low to high), this step of creating the array runs in O(n) time because at each point we just do O(1) work to decide whether or not to add another element onto the end of the array.

Once we have the ranges stored like this, to determine which of the ranges a particular weight falls into, we can just use a binary search to find the largest element smaller than that weight.  For example, to look up 6 in the above array we'd do a binary search to find 3.

Finally, once we have this data structure built up, we can just look at each of the objects one at a time.  For each element, we see how much weight is left, use a binary search in the other structure to see what element it should be paired with to maximize the total value, and then find the maximum attainable value.

Let's trace through an example.  Given maximum allowable weight 10 and the objects

```
Weight | Value
------+------
     2 | 3
     6 | 5
     4 | 7
     7 | 8
```

Let's see what the algorithm does.  First, we need to build up our auxiliary structure for the ranges.  We look at the objects in descending order of value, starting with the object of weight 7 and value 8.  This means that if we ever have at least seven units of weight left, we can get 8 value.  Our array now looks like this:

```
Weight: 7
Value:  8
```

Next, we look at the object of weight 4 and value 7.  This means that with four or more units of weight left, we can get value 7:

```
Weight: 7 4
Value:  8 7
```

Repeating this for the next item (weight six, value five) does not change the array, since if the object has weight six, if we ever had six or more units of free space left, we would never choose this; we'd always take the seven-value item of weight four.  We can tell this since there is already an object in the table whose range includes remaining weight four.

Finally, we look at the last item (value 3, weight 2).  This means that if we ever have weight two or more free, we could get 3 units of value.  The final array now looks like this:

```
Weight: 7 4 2
Value:  8 7 3
```

Finally, we just look at the objects in any order to see what the best option is.  When looking at the object of weight 2 and value 3, since the maximum allowed weight is 10, we need tom see how much value we can get with at most 10 - 2 = 8 weight.  A binary search over the array tells us that this value is 8, so one option would give us 11 weight.  If we look at the object of weight 6 and value 5, a binary search tells us that with five remaining weight the best we can do would be to get 7 units of value, for a total of 12 value.  Repeating this on the next two entries doesn't turn up anything new, so the optimum value found has value 12, which is indeed the correct answer.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

This is similar to [Knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem). I will use naming from it (`num` - weight, `val` - value).

**The essential part:**

1. Start with `a = 0` and `b = n-1`. Assuming `0` is the index of heaviest object and `n-1` is the index of lightest object.
2. Increase `a` til objects `a` and `b` satisfy the limit.
3. Compare current solution with best solution.
4. Decrease `b` by one.
5. Go to `2.`

**Update:**

It's the knapsack problem, except there is a limit of 2 items. You basically need to decide how much space you want for the first object and how much for the other. There is `n` significant ways to split available space, so the complexity is `O(n)`. Picking the most valuable objects to fit in those spaces can be done without additional cost.

Comment: i can't see what is the running time of your algorithm. i hope is not like for the knapsack problem or you would have found a pseudo polynomial(exponential) algo, when a quadratic one is much more easier to archieve; remember that knapsack problem is NP-complete